# SSRS Data Not showing when header and footer are

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

Quick question about SSRS

I am attempting to modify a report in SSRS using Report Builder 3 in SQL Server 2008.

The report is reading from a stored procedure and is meant to show a table of the results of that stored procedure.

I have verified that the stored procedure works, but my problem is that for some reason the header and footer of the report are showing but not the table itself.

Even if no results are returned I would still expect to see the table without any rows.

Has anyone seen this error before?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Does your table have header or footer rows? If there is no data, those will be the only visible components. Also, check the Hidden property of the table. Perhaps the author of the report wrote an expression there that hides the table if it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

If a table is attached to a Dataset that returns zero rows, SSRS will display the contents of the NoRowsMessage property of the table, if anything has been entered, otherwise it will only display the header and footer rows of the table.

This means that if your table doesn't have header and/or footer rows AND your dataset returns zero rows AND there is nothing set for the NoRowsMessage property then nothing would be displayed on the report for that table.